# Как достать строки определенной длины из текста?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Хочу достать строки из теста. Текст разделил с помощью:

```
$preg="/[\s,]+/ui";
$alternate = preg_split($preg,$text);
```

А вот как задать в регулярке слово определенной длинны?

Comment: Используйте `preg_match_all()` и указывайте регулярку с проверкой длины.

Comment: @Visman А подскажи по регулярке плиз. А то я чет не доганю. "/^([\s,]+){4,8}$/ui"

Comment: @dpi вы бы сперва исходную строку написали, а потом - подстроку, которую надо выделить (получить) из исходной строки.

Comment: @Эдуард Я не могу понять правила комбинации в регулярке. Нужна хелп.

Comment: @dpi а я не могу понять, какие именно правила вам не понятны. Вы имеете ввиду синтаксис регулярных выражений?

Comment: @Эдуард как вначале достать слово а потом проверить его длинну. Имеется в виду правило сочетание правил как делать.

Comment: @dpi напишите пример исходной строки, из которой вам нужно достать конкретное слово (слово конкретной длины)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68968/discussion-between--and-dpi).

Comment: @Эдуард это текст любой длинны. переданный через POST . ну например такой  $text=''апишите пример исходной строки, из которой вам нужно достать конкретное слово (слово конкретной длины)" нужон выделить слова не длиннее 5 букв.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Регулярка

```
~\b\p{L}{1,5}\b~u
```

`\b` - граница слова
`\p{L}{1,5}` - от 1 до 5 [букв](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.unicode.php)
`u` - модификатор для обработки строки в режиме UTF-8

```
<?php
$text='напишите пример исходной строки,
из которой вам нужно достать конкретное слово 
(слово конкретной длины)';
if (preg_match_all('~\b\p{L}{1,5}\b~u', $text, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches[0]);    
} else {
    var_dump('Ни чего нет');
}
```

Результат

```
array(6) {
  [0]=> string(4) "из"
  [1]=> string(6) "вам"
  [2]=> string(10) "нужно"
  [3]=> string(10) "слово"
  [4]=> string(10) "слово"
  [5]=> string(10) "длины"
}
```

[Тест](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/82d852e7f48127b0b832698f529e96614ed7d3b0)

P.S. Приведенный вариант будет разбивать слова написанные через дефис на отдельные составляющие. [Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3ca402cb14a7b85d342864cd22cf5cfd74b8284a)

**UPD**
1. Составное слово с дефисом считается единым;
2. Для границы слова использованы конструкции с просмотром вперед/назад, так как `\b` срабатывает на границе между: буква/цифра/знак подчеркивания И не буква/не цифра/не знак подчеркивания

```
~(?<![\p{L}\p{N}-])(?=\p{L})[-\p{L}]{1,5}(?<=\p{L})(?![\p{L}\p{N}-])~u
```

`(?<![\p{L}\p{N}-])(?=\p{L})` - граница слова перед ним (первый символ слова - буква, а перед ней нет ни буквы, ни цифры, ни дефиса)
`[-\p{L}]{1,5}` - слово от 1 до 5 букв или дефисов :)
`(?<=\p{L})(?![\p{L}\p{N}-])` - граница слова после него (последний символ - буква, а после нее нет ни буквы, ни цифры, ни дефиса)

[Тест](https://regex101.com/r/gO46no/4)

**UPD2**
Упрощение второго варианта

```
~\b(?<!-)(?=\p{L})[-\p{L}]{1,5}\b(?<=\p{L})(?!-)~u
```

Вернул границы слова `\b` и оставил для них дополнительные условия на примыкание дефисов к слову и первый/последний символ слова это буквы.
Слова с цифрами не являются словами в этой регулярке.

[Тест](https://regex101.com/r/gO46no/5)

Comment: ну тогда `#\b[-\p{L}]{1,5}\b#u` ? https://regex101.com/r/gO46no/1/

Comment: @Jean-Claude, нет, надо более сложное выражение составлять, а то вот что выходит https://regex101.com/r/gO46no/2

Comment: да, понял что подхватит с дефисом из(-под), p2p - теоретически тоже слово [-\p{L}\p{N}]{1,5}, ну да ладно..

Answer (score -1):

```
$start = 0;
mb_strimwidth($string, $start, $end);
```

Comment: Что это такое?...

Comment: бред какой-то ...

Comment: Обрезает строку, сам задаешь, откуда начать и до куда резать